# How to pass variable through different windows in PyQt5?

Tags: python, class, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two windows, first window is 'FirstWindow' and second is 'Calendar'. first window has one push button (pbSelectDate) and one label (lbDate). calendar window has calendar (CalendarBox) and one push button (pbSelect).

when i click select (pbSelectDate) from first window, calendar window pops up. I select the date and press select button (pbSelect) in the calendar window. i want to print the selected date to the label (lbDate) in the first window.

thanks in advance. :)

this is the first window script.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from Calendar import Ui_CalendarWindow

class Ui_FirstWindow(object):

    def Open_Calendar(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_CalendarWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(654, 242)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lbDate = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 70, 281, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lbDate.setFont(font)
        self.lbDate.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lbDate.setObjectName("lbDate")
        self.pbSelectDate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbSelectDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 191, 61))
        self.pbSelectDate.setObjectName("pbSelectDate")

        self.pbSelectDate.clicked.connect(self.Open_Calendar)

        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lbDate.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Sep"))
        self.pbSelectDate.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Select Date"))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    FirstWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_FirstWindow()
    ui.setupUi(FirstWindow)
    FirstWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is the Calendar window script..

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_CalendarWindow(object):

    def PickedDate(self,var):
        self.selecteddate = self.CalendarBox.selectedDate()
        #print(self.selecteddate.toString('MMM')+'-'+self.selecteddate.toString('yyyy'))

    def setupUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        CalendarWindow.setObjectName("CalendarWindow")
        CalendarWindow.resize(512, 458)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CalendarWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.CalendarBox = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.CalendarBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 464, 289))
        self.CalendarBox.setObjectName("CalendarBox")
        self.pbSelect = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbSelect.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 330, 181, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pbSelect.setFont(font)
        self.pbSelect.setObjectName("pbSelect")

        self.pbSelect.clicked.connect(self.PickedDate)

        CalendarWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(CalendarWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        CalendarWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(CalendarWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CalendarWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CalendarWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("CalendarWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pbSelect.setText(_translate("CalendarWindow", "Select"))



if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    CalendarWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_CalendarWindow()
    ui.setupUi(CalendarWindow)
    CalendarWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not modify the code generated by Qt Designer but create another class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use the initial class to fill it.

**QLabel.setText(const QString )**
Setting the text clears any previous content.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from Calendar import Ui_CalendarWindow
class Ui_CalendarWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        CalendarWindow.setObjectName("CalendarWindow")
        CalendarWindow.resize(512, 458)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CalendarWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.CalendarBox = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.CalendarBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 464, 289))
        self.CalendarBox.setObjectName("CalendarBox")
        self.pbSelect = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbSelect.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 330, 181, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pbSelect.setFont(font)
        self.pbSelect.setObjectName("pbSelect")
#        self.pbSelect.clicked.connect(self.PickedDate)
        CalendarWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(CalendarWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        CalendarWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(CalendarWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CalendarWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, CalendarWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CalendarWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("CalendarWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pbSelect.setText(_translate("CalendarWindow", "Select"))


class Ui_FirstWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):
        FirstWindow.setObjectName("FirstWindow")
        FirstWindow.resize(654, 242)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lbDate = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 70, 281, 131))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lbDate.setFont(font)
        self.lbDate.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.lbDate.setObjectName("lbDate")
        self.pbSelectDate = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pbSelectDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 191, 61))
        self.pbSelectDate.setObjectName("pbSelectDate")
#        self.pbSelectDate.clicked.connect(self.Open_Calendar)
        FirstWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(FirstWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        FirstWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(FirstWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(FirstWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, FirstWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        FirstWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("FirstWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.lbDate.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Sep"))
        self.pbSelectDate.setText(_translate("FirstWindow", "Select Date"))


class CalendarWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_CalendarWindow):              # +
    def __init__(self):
        super(CalendarWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 


class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_FirstWindow):                    # +
    def __init__(self):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)        

        self.pbSelectDate.clicked.connect(self.Open_Calendar)

    def Open_Calendar(self):
        self.window = CalendarWindow()      
        self.window.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

        self.window.pbSelect.clicked.connect(self.PickedDate)

    def PickedDate(self):    # , var
        self.selecteddate = self.window.CalendarBox.selectedDate()
#        print(self.selecteddate.toString('MMM')+'-'+self.selecteddate.toString('yyyy'))  
        self.lbDate.setText(self.selecteddate.toString('ddd-MMM-yyyy'))     # <---     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. you are savior!! Cheers!